# Tabbar App with Paging between tabs

Tags: iphone, paging, uitabbar, tabbar

I've been struggling for about four days now trying to figure out how to implement the functionality I need.  Basically I want to make a tabbar app that you can swipe back and forth between the tabs.  Say I have 4 tabs.  Would it make any sense just to create a scrollview that's 4 times as wide as the device, and load up 4 individual views side by side?  Then I could use the tabbar delegate to simple tell which page to make visible?  I could also use itemSelected to update the tab itself if a user swipes to a new page.

does this make sense / is it a good idea?  I just need a quick yes or no answer before I spend another whole day pursuing something doomed to failure.  Thank you very much for your help...

Answer (score 2):

A page control may help you. Or you can combine navigation controller with tab view. ie use navigate your page on tapping tab buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's a good idea or not aside, one way you could achieve this is to register a `UIGestureRecognizer` on the `UIViewController` in each tab, that when a swipe is detected, changes the tab depending on the direction of the swipe.

Answer (score 0):

My initial idea seemed to work.  I made a UIScrollView with a contentsize width of the four views I needed.  I turned paging on, and used the UITabBar delegate to switch the itemSelected when a new page comes up.  When someone presses a tab, I use the delegate

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)myTab didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item { }
```

to change the contentOffset of my scrollview.  This may not be the best solutions in many cases, however, my app is simple enough that it works quite splendidly for me.

Answer (score 0):

The original question is, how do you enable side-swipe functionality in a tab-bar app implmented using the Storyboard feature.

This question remains unanswered in my opinion.

The way I see it, either the Storyboard tool addresses the problem domain fully, or else who needs it?  If you're forced to do something ridiculous (no offense) like making a 4-page wide view to work around the lack of scrolling, then that it is an argument against the Storyboard.  If you're forced to add code to do something that is in the middle of the Storyboard target feature set, then it's going to be confusing to anyone who comes to the project later - some things are done via Storyboard, some are done in seemingly unrelated code.

Storyboard is a great visual development idea, but it needs to have its capability heaving ramped up and soon.  There is only one answer really to this question;  it should be, just add another behavior element.  The fact that that is not working is a bug or a defect.